# (Done) (Reopen request) Do we want to tell people that resignation letters are the same as exit interviews?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Is it good form to put detailed reasons why you are resigning from a company in a resignation letter?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/184982/)

This question was closed as a duplicate of a question asking about exit interviews. I do not understand why anyone would consider an exit interview to be something that should be treated the same as a resignation letter.

It has been answered, with an answer accepted by the OP, but I think that leaving this question marked as a duplicate does a disservice to any future visitors with the same question.

Comment: I voted to reopen.

Comment: The link opens your answer. I think it should lead users to the actual question https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/184982/is-it-good-form-to-put-detailed-reasons-why-you-are-resigning-from-a-company-in

Comment: @Mari-LouA I found it to link to it from the answer in my profile. Should be fixed now (if anyone ever looks at this again...)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the reopen request.

Just because five people thinks the same information should be shared (or not shared) in both, doesn't mean everybody thinks that way.

There may be very good rationale on why different information, or different levels of detail, may be shared in each step of the resignation process.

Comment: For example, in my opinion the advice I gave in my answer to the question is professional and appropriate for a resignation letter, but would be inappropriate and outright hostile for an exit interview.

Answer (score 0):

It already had 4 votes, I've reopened it. Not a great question but seems valid enough.